# Android resource hungry operations

Tags: android, performance, android-activity, memory-management

1. I am using **JSON** to receive data from the **web service**, creating text to JSON object is resource hungry operation.
2. I have to load images from the web, I am lazy loading images in the async process how can I compress and make the cache ??
3. After the crash, how can I stop re-launching activity?
4. How can I know how much memory remaining and Android OS will kill my object?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can cache your images using a pool of SoftReferences (http://developer.android.com/intl/de/reference/java/lang/ref/SoftReference.html).  This will allow the OS to clean them up if it's running out of memory while still allowing you to access them.  This should help with #2 and #4, but I am not sure what you mean by #3.

Comment: for point 3, when application crash "force close" button appears if you close the application android os re-launch the activity.

Comment: Is that bad?  I mean does your app force close right away, so there is no way to get out of it?